# PHP Form Database Logic

Tags: mysql, database, logic

I'm in the process of building a small system here at work that will track our patients data as we are conducting research for a new drug.

With that said, I'm at a loss on how I should structure the data for one aspect of this. We have several forms that must be completed for each patient. Not each patient will have all forms completed for them at the same time. No two forms have the same questions, same answers, or same number of questions. I have come up with the structure for the patient information and other general info, but I do not know how to structure this section with the forms.

The way the users want the pages to work is that they would have a main page where they click on the study, then the patient name, and then there would be a list of all the completed forms for that patient (as well as a button to complete a new form).

Would it be best to create a new table for each form and then do some huge union query to show the list of completed forms? That doesn't seem like an efficient way to do this? Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

first of all

i will say KEEP YOUR DATABASE SIMPLE

first Create a Main table with patients names imp MAIN information

then observes your forms and excludes extra information

for a example i m patient (pray NOt)

my user id is 1 in main table

and in form 1 and form 2

you can SELECT LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM form1,form2 WHERE patient_ID = '1'
```

it is just a sample

Comment: That's my goal is to keep it as simple as possible.

So, I could put the patient's ID in the table and select based on that criteria. Can you select FROM multiple tables in a single query like that?

Comment: Found a way to make this way simpler than I was making it out to be. Thanks for the help - you got my brain a moving.

Comment: i checked on google and php manual yes you can php is easy flexiable language you will do more you will learn more :) just start with simple:)